# Right way to show a series of thumbnails with Qt and Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, thumbnails

I am doing a project with Qt and Python. According to a set of parameters, I retrieve a set of images from a folder.

I would like to show the result images as a set of thumbnails in my Qt UI. My desired output would be something like:

```
Image1    Image2    Image3
Image4    Image5    ......
......    ......    ImageN
```

Where instead of each string I have a thumbnail. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: [QGridLayout](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qgridlayout.html)?

Comment: yeah! great, i didn't think about that..put it as an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QGridLayout](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qgridlayout.html) seems to be what you are looking for. Quoting the documentation:

> The QGridLayout class lays out widgets in a grid.
>
> QGridLayout takes the space made available to it (by its parent layout
>   or by the parentWidget()), divides it up into rows and columns, and
>   puts each widget it manages into the correct cell.